# .on detects only first change

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to pass changes in input field to a variable simultaneously with the change.  But for some reason, my code detects only first change. For example, if I enter "100" into the field, it only detects "1". Nothing happens afterwards.

Here is my jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var wholeshort = $(".shorcodeval").val();
  a = wholeshort;
  var w = /width="(.*?)"/.exec(a)[1];
  $(".widthinput").on('input', function() {
    nw = $(this).val();
    wholeshort = wholeshort.replace(w, nw);
    $(".shorcodeval").val(wholeshort);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="widthinput" />
<textarea class="shorcodeval">[example width="300px"]</textarea>
```

here is the fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/3a6n1fux/

Comment: Please edit your question and type Ctrl+M or click the `<>` button to make a snippet showing your issue.

Comment: You have a global variable `wholeshort` that you modify with each input. So if it is `wholeshort` is `1` after the first `input` event, then what should `'1'.replace(w, nw)` produce?

Comment: Please create a  minimal, complete and verifiable example including all necessary variables, like `wholeshort` and  `w`.

Comment: There are three vars we don't see the scope of here; wholeshort, w, and nw. Please post ALL the code that references these as your issue is likely related to the variable scopes.

Comment: Will add in a sec

Comment: Note that since you assign nw each time, you should probably limit its scope with var or let (browser compat with let)

Comment: tried it. Didn't work

Comment: I didn't say that was the problem, just that you should always limit scope to avoid global hoisting. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that after the first `input` you save `[example width="1"]` in `wholeshort`, but `w` is `300px` so you try to replace `300px` in `[example width="1"]`.

To solve that you would need to save the result of `wholeshort.replace(w, nw)` in an own variable or pass it directly to  `.val(wholeshort.replace(w, nw))`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var wholeshort = $(".shorcodeval").val();
  var w = /width="(.*?)"/.exec(a)[1];
  
  $(".widthinput").on('input', function() {
    var nw = $(this).val();
    $(".shorcodeval").val(wholeshort.replace(w, nw));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="widthinput" />
<textarea class="shorcodeval">[example width="300px"]</textarea>
```

Comment: yep! That's it. Thank you!